# Process multiple Async Calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

I have a List of Books with basic info such as IDs and I need to call multiple external API Endpoints to get the rest of the info, per example images, refs, author bio, etc.

Here is one way that has a bad performance since is retrieving the info like synchronous way (one at the time)...

```
foreach (var book in books)
{
    book.Images = await GetImagesAsync(book.ID);
    book.Refs = await GetLinksReferencesAsync(book.ID);
    book.AuthorBio = await GetAuthorBioAsync(book.ID);
}
```

Ultimately what I want is to get the advantage of `async` calls and make like 100 calls at the same time.

One improve will be adding `Task.WaitAll()` inside of the `foreach`, but the only gain will be doing 3 requests at the time. But how can I improve this using  `async` calls in more efficient way, like 100 requests at the time?

Comment: you are wanting to look up `Parallel Processing` do not get the two mixed up

Comment: Well, you could change that `foreach` into a `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: @MethodMan I think the OP wants both parallel and asynchronous processing.

Comment: You could keep a list of tasks and just loop over all your books, start all your tasks and put them in your list. Outside of the loop you can then just call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to await the completion of all your 3*Number-of-books tasks at once. However, depending on the number tasks and their resource requirements this might get slow at some point due to resource congestion. So might need to create batches, i.e. only process 33 books at once to limit execution to 99 tasks.

Comment: This post may be helpful to you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/

Comment: @ckuri The approach of processing it by batches works for me. The key was adding `ContinueWith` and looks something like this:  `tasks.Add(GetImagesAsync(book.ID).ContinueWith(b => dicBooks[book.ID].Images = b.Result));`

Comment: @Jaider You should pretty much never be using `ContinueWith`.  It's basically always better to be using `await`.  It's quite difficult to use `ContinueWith` correctly, particularly when it comes to error handling semantics, which you did not do correctly in that example.

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use [TPL's dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline) for this sort of thing. It allows you to chain together multiple async operations (and synchronous ones too) to form a 'pipeline' and has a myriad of tweaks to control the degree of parallelism, memory buffer size, etc. at each stage.

There are various types of 'block' you can use to make up a pipeline. Perhaps the simplest is a `TransformBlock<T1,T2>`, which takes a function mapping `T1` to `T2`. There are also `ActionBlock<T>` which performs an action (but does not return a value so is effectively a termination point to the pipeline) and many more such as: `TransformManyBlock<T1,T2>`, `BatchingBlock<T>`, join blocks, etc for more complex pipelines.

For your own example you could set up the pipeline as follows.

First we define some default options (here, for example we specify a max buffer size of 100 books and a max degree of parallelism of 15 simultaneous jobs):

```
var defaultOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    BoundedCapacity = 100,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15
};
```

Now define an `TransformBlock<Book,Book>` for the first 2 `GetXAsync` jobs and an ActionBlock for the last one to terminate our pipeline using the default options each time:

```
var getImagesBlock = new TransformBlock<Book, Book>(async b =>
{
    b.Images = await GetImagesAsync(b.ID);
    return b;
}, defaultOptions);

var getLinksBlock = new TransformBlock<Book, Book>(async b =>
{
    b.Refs = await GetLinksReferencesAsync(b.ID);
    return b;
}, defaultOptions);

var getAuthorBioBlock = new ActionBlock<Book>(async b =>
{
    b.AuthorBio = await GetAuthorBioAsync(b.ID);
}, defaultOptions);
```

Now we define some settings governing how we link the blocks (explore these for what works best for your own solution!):

```
var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions
{
    PropagateCompletion = true //when an earlier block signals it is 'Complete' and has no more messages the next block completes too after it has finished any existing messages
};
```

then we join up all 3 of our blocks to make the pipeline:

```
getImagesBlock.LinkTo(getImagesBlock, linkOptions);
getLinksBlock.LinkTo(getAuthorBioBlock, linkOptions);
```

Now all that we need to do is pass in each book to the start of the pipeline:

```
foreach (var book in books)
{
    getImagesBlock.Post(book); // or we could use SendAsync if this is inside an async method
}
```

Signal to the first block that we have finished sending books in:

```
getImagesBlock.Complete();
```

then wait for the last block to finish processing:

```
getAuthorBioBlock.Completion.Wait(); // or await getAuthorBioBlock.Completion; if inside an async method
```

I think using the dataflow options, once you get used to them, provide a natural, easy to use and widely applicable solution for a great many parallel operations like this one. I'd recommend taking the time to learn how to use it. It really makes this type of job much easier to manage and optimise.

A couple of things to note in passing:

- I have assumed that each operation on a given `book` has to be performed sequentially as is the case in the OP.
- There is nothing to stop us using a different buffer size or degree of parallelism at each block. If (as is often the case) different blocks have operations of different types or cost then we can optimise each step according to its own performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var book in books)
{
    var imagesTask = GetImagesAsync(book.ID);
    var refsTask = GetLinksReferencesAsync(book.ID);
    var authorTask = GetAuthorBioAsync(book.ID);

    Task.WaitAll(imagesTask, refsTask, authorTask);

    book.Images = imagesTask.Result;
    book.Refs = refsTask.Result;
    book.AuthorBio = authorTask.Result;
}
```

In this approach, three asynchronous tasks are executed simultaneously.

Comment: You're waiting synchronously, not asynchronously, and not allowing operations from multiple books to be done in parallel, as mentioned as being important in the question.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, many books will be processed one at a time. But inside `Task.WaitAll` three tasks waiting asynchronously.

Comment: No, they're waiting *synchronously*, not asynchronously.  And the question specifically states that it's a *problem* that the books are processed sequentially, not in parallel.

Comment: @Servy - https://dotnetfiddle.net/BPmuTZ - result time 3 seconds, not 9.

Comment: I didn't say they ran sequentially, I said they're running synchronously.  You're not processing each book asynchronously.  You're blocking, synchronously.  That's what `WaitAll` does.

Comment: @Servy - However, I admit, I didn't read a question carefully.

Answer (score -2):

Here is making 50 x 3 request at the time... one thing to consider it is to check for errors, and what to do when that occurs, like should continue the requests or stop?

```
var books = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => new Book { ID = i }).ToArray();
var tasks = new List<Task>(50);
var max = 50;
var counter = 0;
foreach (var book in books)
{
    var bookTask = SetBookInfoAsync(book);
    tasks.Add(bookTask);
    counter++;
    if (counter >= max)
    {
        var finishTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(finishTask);
    }
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach (var book in books)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Book Id {book.ID} {book.Images[0]} {book.Refs[0]} {book.AuthorBio}");
}

async Task SetBookInfoAsync(Book book)
{
    book.Images = await GetImagesAsync(book.ID);
    book.Refs = await GetLinksReferencesAsync(book.ID);
    book.AuthorBio = await GetAuthorBioAsync(book.ID);
    // you can change this as well to WhenAll() if need it
}
async Task<List<string>> GetImagesAsync(int id)
{
    await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(1, 100));
    return ["image:" + id];
}
async Task<List<string>> GetLinksReferencesAsync(int id)
{
    await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(1, 100));
    return ["ref:" + id];
}
async Task<string> GetAuthorBioAsync(int id)
{
    await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(1, 100));
    return "author:" + id;
}
```

the output:

[image]